# addsubview and removeFromSuperview is this effecient way to display nextview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm using the below code snippet to navigate through UI's in my app,

```
UIView *viewOb = [self.view superview];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
NextVC *nextOb = [[NextVC alloc] init];
[viewOb addSubview:nextOb.view];
[secOb release];
```

i don't know whether this is correct way to move to the next view,is this cause memory leaks?or this is safer compared to pushviewcontroller? and i'm not navigating between views, i just want to move to next view and in next view on click of back button i need to come to previous page.
can anyone help me,any help is appreciated in advance, Thank You.

Comment: do you want to navigate to other view ? if I am not wrong

Comment: Not sure about the context of "navigation". Is it drill-down or modal navigation style?

Comment: i am not navigating between views, i just want to move to next view.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not an advised way for navigation. Please use NavigationController for navigation. Alternatively you can also use

```
[self presentModalViewController]
```

function for navigation.

Comment: this is the best way to navigate between views, @rahul the way you are following produces memory leaks on sequential loading of same view.(you cannot observe it in one flow).Better dont use it

Comment: @rahulchoudary sorry the comment is for rahul dravid. If the navigation is in the way he is doing, it produces memory leaks(But you cannot observe it in just one flow-- load and unload, if it repeats then it produces memory problem).

Comment: Just to add-on: presentModalViewController can't work on UIView (from op question), presentModalViewController should be for UIView Controller

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to navigate between views you should use `UINavigationController`